# HTTPClient ntlm smart card

Tags: proxy, httpclient, ntlm, smartcard

Using HTTPClient 4 and want to authenticate via a proxy with NTLM....

But the authenticate data should be pulled from my smart card and hard cert.  Haven't found examples of this with HTTPClient (only using basic with user/pass).

Eclipse in it's proxy settings must do something similar behind the scenes along with the subversion Eclipse extension.  Both just ask for the proxy host and port, nothing more.  Something? has to pull my identification from the smart card into the call.  Assuming it is NTLM?

Any ideas?

Comment: Got a hint that the NTCredentials has to be populated by the user of the HTTPClient.  Which means I need to access the SmartCard myself in order to instantiate the NTCredentials object.  Question is how?  And how does the Eclipse IDE do it?

Comment: Found my answer at http://old.nabble.com/HTTPClient-ntlm-smart-card-td34070660.html#a34076579.